# Installing LiveCd Ubuntu Based

Tags: ubuntu, installation, vmware-player, livecd, kernel-panic

I just bought the ebook Hacking the art of exploitation (Link: http://www.nostarch.com/hacking2.htm#updates) and I downloaded the livecd which came along with it(Link: http://www.nostarch.com/hackingCD.htm). I was trying to use it using Vmwareplayer by creating a virtual machine.

I was able to go ahead and make the machine and everything to reach its main interface.
When I click it to start, "Start Hacking LiveCD (Ubuntu Linux)", I get lots of commands and then this error
<0> Kernel Panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt error

Please help me solve it. I am new to this and I have no idea what to do.
I was looking in the internet and it stated to carry out some commands, but I don't understand where should I use them in vmware player.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Microsoft Virtual PC (2007), if you are running on a windows machine. Alternatively if you can't use it virtually, you could install it onto a flash drive. Also you could dual boot meaning that you keep your current operating system and install ubuntu also. Here is a guide on that, I will assume you're running windows: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

For that guide follow the "install ubuntu after windows" section.

Comment: THe weird part is that I can run ubuntu on my vmware. But I am unable to run this specific livecd from the book. Any suggestions to get it running on Vmware Player?

Answer (score 0):

Still running in to this problem on Ubuntu 16.04 with VMWare Player 12.
Looks like if you change the emulated disk drive hardware back to ide from sata it runs fine.

My only guess is that the 2.6 kernel had some issues with Sata at the time?